# SQLite Query - Group By Contiguous Sequence

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am looking for sql to run on SQLite.

I have this table (3 integer columns) and data (here is a subset of the data)

```
ID  aid adur
1   1   5
2   3   7
3   3   8
4   3   5
5   2   9
6   1   9
7   1   2
```

I want the following adur result in which the table is a) sorted from largest ID to smallest and b) when 2 or more aids are the same continguously, the adurs are summed.

```
ID  aid adur    adur 
7   1   2       11
6   1   9
5   2   9       9
4   3   5       20
3   3   8   
2   3   7   
1   1   5       5
```

I tried the following. It does not provide the desired result because it groups/sums all adurs in the table at once vs grouping/summing just those adurs are the same back to back (contiguously).

```
SELECT Min(act_test.ID) AS MinOfID, act_test.aid, Sum(act_test.adur) AS SumOfadur
FROM act_test
GROUP BY act_test.aid
ORDER BY Min(act_test.ID) DESC
```

Comment: do you need the sum on all rows for a given `aid`?

Comment: thanks! Only those rows that are contiguous. (back to back). in the above last table example...the desired result for all aid 1s is first 11 (adur 9 + adur 2 because these two 1s are back to back) and 5 because this adur/row is alone. The same goes for aid 2. The answer is 9 because there is only one aid 2. And for aid 3, there are three back to back so the sum of these three adurs is 20.

Comment: can there be more than 3 contiguous rows in the table?

Comment: yes there can be more than 3 contiguous rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, g.SumAdur
FROM
    Table t
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT
          r.aid
          ,MIN(r.Id) as MinId
          ,MAX(r.Id) as MaxId
          ,SUM(r.adur) as SumAdur
       FROM
          (
             SELECT *
                ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table tc
                    WHERE t.Id >= tc.Id AND t.aid = tc.aid) as RowNum
             FROM
                Table t
          )r
       GROUP BY
          r.aid
          ,r.Id - r.RowNum
    ) g
    ON t.Id = g.MaxId
ORDER BY
    t.Id DESC
```

Create A `Partitioned Row Number` Subtract it from the `ID` to create the grouping and do the math then match back.  This method requires the `ID` to be an incremental number with no gaps.  If `ID` could have gaps then you just need to create a `Row Number` across the entire table as well and then use that to create the grouping.

If `ID` has gaps use this one:

```
SELECT t.*, g.SumAdur
FROM
    Table t
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT
          r.aid
          ,MIN(r.Id) as MinId
          ,MAX(r.Id) as MaxId
          ,SUM(r.adur) as SumAdur
       FROM
          (
             SELECT *
                ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table tc
                    WHERE t.Id >= tc.Id AND t.aid = tc.aid) as AidRowNum
                ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table tc
                    WHERE t.Id >= tc.Id) as IdRowNum                
             FROM
                Table t
          )r
       GROUP BY
          r.aid
          ,r.IdRowNum - r.AidRowNum
    ) g
    ON t.Id = g.MaxId
ORDER BY
    t.Id DESC
```

And if you want the value to be shown on every row just change:

```
ON t.Id = g.MaxId
```

TO

```
ON t.Id BETWEEN g.MinId AND g.MaxId
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks Matt. Does SQLite support all of the syntax above?